# Pockect PC WCF implement Windows authentication

Tags: wcf-security, pocketpc

I need to implement windows authentication on a windows Pocket PC 5.0 when connecting to the WCF service. Is it possible to let the user enter their credentials which can then be passed to the WCF service for it to authenticate against?

I realize that pocket PC applications do not have an app.config where impersonation details can be put in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. Had to change the security type in the WCF to Windows (from NTLM)

In the pocket pc application, I had to specify the service URL and create a network credential passing in the user details.

Works now :)

```
proxy.Url = "http://sds-ws65/MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif50/table1service.svc";
            proxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
```